# Postgres matching against an array of regular expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql

My client wants the possibility to match a set of data against an array of regular expressions, meaning:

```
table:
name   | officeId (foreignkey)
--------
bob    | 1
alice  | 1 
alicia | 2
walter | 2
```

and he wants to do something along those lines:

get me all records of offices (officeId) where there is a member with

```
ANY name ~ ANY[.*ob, ali.*]
meaning
ANY of[alicia, walter] ~ ANY of [.*ob, ali.*] results in true
```

I could not figure it out by myself sadly :/.

**Edit**

The real Problem was missing form the original description:

I cannot use `select disctinct officeId .. where name ~ ANY[.*ob, ali.*]`, because:

This application, stored data in postgres-xml columns, which means i do in fact have (after evaluating `xpath('/data/clients/name/text()'))::text[]`):

```
table:
name              | officeId (foreignkey)
-----------------------------------------
[bob, alice]      | 1
[anthony, walter] | 2
[alicia, walter]  | 3
```

There is the Problem. And "you don't do that, that is horrible, why would you do it like this, store it like it is meant to be stored in a relation database, user a no-sql database for Document-based storage, use json" are no options.

I am stuck with this datamodel.

Comment: can you not use `name ~'.*ob' or name ~'ali.*'`?

Comment: `... where name ~ any(array['.*ob', 'ali.*'])`

Comment: Would be nice if i could do it this simple, i just realized that what i wrote does not express the core of the problem, which is the underlying crazy datamodel that was chosen before is entered the Project. - i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty horrific, but the only way I can think of doing such a thing would be a hybrid of a cross-join and a semi join.  On small data sets this would probably work pretty well.  On large datasets, I imagine the cross-join component could hit you pretty hard.

Check it out and let me know if it works against your real data:

```
with patterns as (
  select unnest(array['.*ob', 'ali.*']) as pattern
)
select
  o.name, o.officeid
from
  office o
where exists (
  select null
  from patterns p
  where o.name ~ p.pattern
)
```

The semi-join helps protect you from cases where you have a name like "alicia nob" that would meet multiple search patterns would otherwise come back for every match.

Comment: As there will be ~10.000.000 records i quess is cannot do with any solution that cannot use an index :/

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the array to text.

```
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE (xpath('/data/clients/name/text()', xml_field))::text ~ ANY(ARRAY['wal','ant']);
```

When casting a string array into text, strings containing special characters or consisting of keywords are enclosed in double quotes kind of like `{jimmy,"walter, james"}` being two entries. Also when matching with `~` it is matched against any part of the string, not the same as `LIKE` where it's matched against the whole string.

Here is what I did in my test database:

```
test=# select id, (xpath('/data/clients/name/text()', name))::text[] as xss, officeid from workers WHERE (xpath('/data/clients/name/text()', name))::text ~ ANY(ARRAY['wal','ant']);
 id |           xss           | officeid 
----+-------------------------+----------
  2 | {anthony,walter}        |        2
  3 | {alicia,walter}         |        3
  4 | {"walter, james"}       |        5
  5 | {jimmy,"walter, james"} |        4
(4 rows)
```

Comment: that would of course work, but is there a way to make this also work with =, <, > operators, i just see this working with LIKE or ~

Comment: I don't know what that would look like, but perhaps a better option would be for you to define some functions that take arrays using `CREATE FUNCTION` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html